# MySQL Statement in java with the where clause referring to column using table name

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a table in `mysql` which has a column called `CREATE` which I need to access from Java like this:

```
  Select GRPLABEL,APPID,TOOLTIP from myTable where GRPID='"+mapGroupId+"' AND myTable.CREATE='X';
```

I get an error when trying to call this method from `java` using the `mysql driver` but not from the `mysql workbench`

What is the correct way of making a request in this case?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: `MySQLSyntaxException Unknown column myTable.CREATE in the where clause`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Select GRPLABEL,APPID,TOOLTIP from myTable a  where a.GRPID='"+mapGroupId+"' AND a.CREATE='X';

Answer (score 0):

Surround your table and column names with ` symbol.

Comment: can i know please why?

Comment: @user2309862 post DDL definition of your table, please.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please specify the type of data for GRPID ? If its an integer value, you don't need the single quote.

It would be useful if you could put up the create statement for this table.